# Up and bottom keys block

Tags: javascript, block

I have one Jscript that uses up and down keys but when user click up or down page is scrolling but how to block scroll when user click up or down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
return false;
```

At the end of the event handler.  See [this quirksmode.org article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link4) for more information.